# JavaExec task is always executing

Tags: gradle

I have the following task

```
task antlr4(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "org.antlr.v4.Tool"
    args = project.getAntlrArgs()
    classpath =  configurations.compile
}

classes {
    it.dependsOn([antlr4])
}
```

The antlr4 task has to execute before compiling java because ANTLR4 generates a few java files.

The problem is that it executes every time any task executes (For example when running the `clean` task), I want it to execute only before compiling java files.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please don't generate unnecessary work by double-posting here and on http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, Thanks for the suggestion, I will refrain from doing that. I am unable to delete the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you posted won't lead to `antlr4` always being executed. The problem must be elsewhere in the build script. If Java compilation requires files generated by the `antlr4` task, you'll have to do `compileJava.dependsOn(antlr4)`, not `classes.dependsOn(antlr4)`. Or, following your syntax, `compileJava { dependsOn(antlr4) }` (you can omit `it.` and `[]`).